# Using filtered column of email addresses in Excel to create new email

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA 2013 want to use a selection of filtered cells in excel as a source of email addresses to be passed to a procedure that generates a new email.

My data looks like this:

[image]

I have a line of code which should select all data (email addresses) in column B after the header row:

```
Dim recipients As String
....
recipients = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("B6" & .Rows.Count).Value), ";")
```

This line produces an error Invalid or Unqualified Reference.

The recipients string is later passed to the email procedure. For completeness the email VBA is:

```
With OutMail
  .Subject = "Some subject"
  .Body = "Get a body for the email"
  .To = recipients
  .Importance = olImportanceHigh
  .Display
End With
```

Comment: You're probably missing a `With` somewhere in your `....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can iterate the filtered cells in code:

```
Dim recipients As String
Dim recipient As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Or ActiveSheet
   For Each recipient In .Range("B6:B" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
      recipients = recipients + recipient + ";"
   Next recipient
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Your range needs to be: `Range("B6:B" & .Rows.Count)`

2: You should restrict rows to the used area `Range("B6:B" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count)`

3: To select only the filtered cells you need to add `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Something like this:

```
recipients = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("B6:B" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value), ";")
```

4: It is probably better to iterate the cells in code instead of using Transpose/Join: Otherwise you may get an error when only 1 email address is filtered, or no emails are visible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about iterate. Do you have a link or example?

Comment: I have added an alternative answer showing how to iterate the filtered cells in code, as the comments cannot be formatted. You can adapt as needed,